# How to dynamically select module with modern nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using `node --experimental-modules test.mjs` (NodeJs v11.9.0).

There are many options to implement the same class, and I need to swith by terminal,

```
switch (process.argv[2]) {
  case 'a':
    import MyClass from './MyClass-v1.mjs'; break;
  case 'b':
    import MyClass from './MyClass-v2.mjs'; break;
  default:
    import MyClass from './MyClass-v3.mjs';
}
```

ERROR on `import MyClass`: Unexpected identifier

PS: working fine when using **isolated** `import MyClass from './MyClass-v3.mjs';`.

---

NOTE: `const MyClass = require('./MyClass-v3.mjs')`  not works with modern Javascript.  (*ReferenceError: require is not defined*). The file have only a class definition,

```
export default class MyClass { ... }
```

---

PS: there are nothing like [C_preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) for NodeJs?  An old **pre-compiler** (with some argv access) will be fine here.

Comment: Hi. Probably you need to use Factory pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Hi @VladKosko, make sense... What the best way to implement it with Node? No easy way to dynamic loading? My code is also a kind of [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Comment: The import statement is only allowed at the top level of modules. To import anywhere else use `require`.

Comment: Hi @DanD., I edited, using modern Node. *"ReferenceError: require is not defined"*.

Comment: You will need a [dynamic import](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) for this, you cannot put an import declaration inside a switch case. Not sure though whether node already supports `import()`.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, as I expressed *"working fine when using isolated `import ...` "*, the `import()` clause is valid, the problem is to use (how to?) in a `switch` clause.

Comment: Something like `import(getModuleName(process.argv[2])).then(MyClass => { … });` probably, where `getModuleName` can do anything to resolve the argument (using `switch`, `if`/`else`, an object literal, a `Map`, or something else)

Comment: @Bergi  I try `import(file).then(MyClass);` but error, "ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined".  I try `import(file).then(MyClass => {});`  same error. The `getModuleName()` is easy, we need the basic thing first, to load a class.

Comment: ... Seems that Node v11.9  not supports things like `const MyClass = await import('./file.mjs')` ,  error at  `await`,  "SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word".  The most simple, `const MyClass = import(file);`   works, but not as expected, *"TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor"*.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Using promises, you need to put all the code that uses `MyClass` inside that callback (where I put the elision). If you want to use `await`, you need to put that code in an `async function` (which you can make an IIFE, though).

Comment: @Bergi, no, as **only a version test**, I not need, I need sync... As I edited, any NodeJs pre-compiler (exist?) will be also a solution.

Comment: @PeterKrauss You cannot do synchronous dynamic imports with ES6 modules. Given that this code seems to be located in your main.js, doing it asynchronously should not be a problem.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, I can use assync, but not ugly syntax/control with event listener where I need a trivial import.

Comment: @Bergi, using the encapsulated form `import('./MyClass.mjs').then(MyClass => { let x = new MyClass(); console.log( x ) });`  the error is *(node:10431) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: MyClass  is not a constructor
    at then.MyClass (file:///...:10:11)
(node:10431) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
(node:10431) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections..."*

Comment: @PeterKrauss Ah right, `import()` resolves to the namespace object, not to the default export. You'd need to use `then(({default: MyClass}) => …)` or `const {default: MyClass} = await …`

Comment: YES, first suggestion is working! Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189353/discussion-between-peter-krauss-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Javascript (ES6+) implementations are under construction, some syntax are working with NodeJS (`node --experimental-modules`) and good *browsers*, other not.

This is the only way to do without cost of "load all" (see @Markus solution), but with the cost of non-global import, needs an ugly block to define scope and assyncronous operation... First step is to understand the basic impor block syntax:

```
import('./MyClass-v3.mjs').then(({default: MyClass}) => {
    // can use MyClass only here in this block
    let x = new MyClass();
    console.log("DEBUG=",x);
});
```

Them, putting all together, the argv selection and the optional imports.

### Solution

```
const classes = {
  a: './MyClass-v1.mjs'
  ,b: './MyClass-v3.mjs'
  ,c: './MyClass-v3.mjs'
};
import(classes[process.argv[2]] || classes.c ).then(({default: MyClass}) => {
    let x = new MyClass();
    console.log("DEBUG=",x);
});
```

PS: some of the magic (no rational) is to use `({default: MyClass})` instead `(MyClass)`.

---

### Thanks

To @Bergi (!), for explain this solution (see question comments).

Answer (score 2):

```
import ClassV1 from './MyClass-v1.mjs';
import ClassV2 from './MyClass-v2.mjs'; 
import ClassV3 from './MyClass-v3.mjs';

const classes = {
  a: ClassV1,
  b: ClassV2
}

const Class = classes[process.argv[2]] || ClassV2;
```

You could also write an index file with all the classes and do an `import * as classes from 'classes.mjs';`.

Comment: Hi, is a valid solution because it works (!), but it is in the opposite of the "import only necessary" philosophy... An old pre-compiler solution will be better.

Comment: You can not do a precompiler solution if you don't know at compile time which class you want. So all modules have to be available at runtime.
But if you want a precompiler, this is probably the closest you get:
https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/
Use can use codeshift for the transformation:
https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift